# Android webview multiple windows

Tags: android, android-webview

I am experiencing difficulties with webviews. I have a webview that loads webppage with a form. The form has a target _blank attribute. I need the webview to open a new webview window with the form's action url loaded. I have applied the following code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web = new WebView(this);        
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    web.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/formpage");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {
         /* multiple webview window overload method - start */
         public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg)
         {
             WebView newWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());

             WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
             transport.setWebView(newWebView);
             resultMsg.sendToTarget();
             return true;
         }

         /* multiple webview window overload method - end */
    });  

    setContentView(web);  
}
```

Nothing happens when I click on the forms submit button.

Comment: add newWebView to dialog things will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert your new WebView into the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

please try from this and i think it will help you.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
private TextView header_maintext;
private TextView headeroptiontext;
private RelativeLayout back;
private String url_string="http://www.google.com";
private String header_maintext_string="tittle";  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);


     url_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
     header_maintext_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("header_text");

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    header_maintext= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_maintext);
    header_maintext.setText(header_maintext_string);

    headeroptiontext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headeroptiontext);
    headeroptiontext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

      back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
      back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
                {
                    webview.goBack();
                }
            else
                {
                    finish();
                }
         }
    });

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "tittle", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl(url_string);


}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                webview.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
```